# How to count the number of items (or length) of cell in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, count, apply, string-length

**In this small dataframe:**

```
d1 = pd.read_csv('to_count.mcve.txt', sep='\t')

      M1          M2          F1 
      A,B,A,C,D   A,C,B,C,B   A 
      A,B,B,C,B   A,B,A       B 
      C,B,C,D,E   B,C         E
```

**Step 01:**

I want to count **how many of the values in F1 are in M1 and M2**

I can do:

```
d1_count = d1.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.count(x.F1), 1)
```

Output:

```
        M1  M2  F1              
        2   1   1  
        3   1   1 
        1   0   1
```

**Step 02:** but I want to divide the count by 2 if the length of the original cell was more than 3 (excluding commas).

Explanation:

- all the values in M1 have length more than 3, the very first M2 has length more than 3. So, counts for these needs to be changed (divide by 2).
- the first value in M1 is `A,B,A,C,D`
- The F1 values is `A` and there are 2 'A' in M1 which is counted using `.str.count(x.F1)`
- since the length of `A,B,A,C,D` is more than 3. I now change the count (divided by 2), resulting in 1.
- I want to do this for all the columns automatically, since there will be a lots of columns.

Final expected output would be:

```
     M1     M2                   
     1     0.5
     1.5   1
     0.5   0
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: what is a "cell", what is its "length"?

Comment: You can use a sum...

Comment: Each cell in a pandas dataframe is a intersection of `columns and rows`. The very first cell is with the data `A,B,A,C,D`

Comment: "cell" is not standard terminology, I know what you mean but it helps if you are precise. What are you working with, strings? And what do you mean by "length"? The string length? or the number of letters in your string, not including the commas?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Can you suggest how? I can count the length of each cell, but that is not what I want. I want: to count the number of values of `F1` in `M1 and M2`, but if the original length of the `M1 and M2` are over certain length, I want to divide that count by 2.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: yes they are strings at first. But, I am trying to count the number of values from `F1` in `M1 and M2` column. But, if the original length was ever more than certain threshold (say 5) then the final count is divided by two.

Comment: OK, but *what do you mean by length*. If your values are strings, then length implies `len(my_str)`, but that is likely not what you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: finding the length isn't a problem. The length is just a condition. Please read the question, I think I have explained it clearly. **What I want ** - I want to calculate the instances of `F1` in each column, which is already resolved. But, one step further: I want to divide these counts by 2 if the length of that row/col intersection (or say cell) was greater than 3. Is it clear??

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your "cells" in the `M1` column are strings separated by commas. It might be easier to first convert this into a list rather than a string, so your manipulations make sense. Something like this:

```
df['M1_list'] = df['M1'].apply(lambda x: x.split(","))
```

Now you have a column called `M1_list` where each entry has a list. Now you can use `.apply()` again to get the number you want.

```
df['F1_count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['M1_list'].count(x['F1']), axis=1)
```

But this only gives you the count of the number of items from `F1` in `M1_list`. To get the condition that "if you have more than 3 items divide the count by 2" you can either do another `.apply`:

```
df['F1_count'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['F1_count'] / 2 if len(x['M1']) >= 3 else x['F1_count'], axis=1)
```

You can of course combine these into a single `.apply` statement if you want. But it makes code easier to read if you split up complex operations. One way you could combine this is with an auxiliary function instead of using a `lambda`:

```
def compute_F1(row):
    M1_list = row['M1'].split(",")
    f1_count = M1_list.count(row['F1'])
    if (len(M1_list) >= 3):
        return f1_count / 2
    else:
        return f1_count
```

And then apply that function to each row:

```
df['F1_count'] = df.apply(lambda x: compute_F1(x), axis=1)
```

And you should have your result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I am trying to apply this to my data where there are lots of column. So, i don't want to specify specific columns (like `df['M1']`). I tried to work it out using df[::] and several other methods, but couldn't get it done. Any suggestions.

Comment: You can just write a for loop to loop around all columns. For future reference, if things like that are important to your solution you should mention it in your original post.

Comment: Yeah my bad. Actually I was able to do the count on all the columns using **df_count = df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.count(x.F1), 1)** but I can't just insert the condition. Tried applymap which then became worst. I am pulling my hair here, lol 

Comment: If you're not using my suggestion I can't really help you... You really should change it to a list first

Comment: I think you mean question. I will change it

Comment: Just changed it, but looks like the question addresses that in a subtle way.

Comment: No, I mean instead of manipulating strings you should be manipulating lists. It will make "taking the length" much easier. Please look at my suggested solution and see if you can make that work for you.

Comment: Creating the list won't help with automating the process for whole columns. I can try the for-loop but I think with big data I am will be running into memory constraints. I wanted to simply do `df.apply(lambda x: x.loc[::].str.split(',').count(x.F1)`. You can see that the split is already creating a list on the fly. The main problem is **how can I put the condition of counting the length of same x and change it based on the required condition**. Btw, thanks for the help. I realize there is more reading for me to do.